# rename specific file extension in directory with match to another file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a specific set (all ending with `.bam`) of downloaded files in a directory `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-15-2016`.  What I am trying to do is use a match to `$2` in `name` to rename the downloaded files.  To make things a more involved the date of the folder is unique and in the header of `name` the date of the match exists and is where the match in `name` is located. I am not sure how to do this or if it is possible.  Thank you :).

**contents of folder `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-15-2016`**

```
IonXpress_001.bam
IonXpress_002.bam
IonXpress_003.bam
IonXpress_007.bam
file1.gz
file2.gz
```

**name**

```
2-15-2016
IonXpress_001.bam testname1_12345
IonXpress_002.bam testname2_45678
IonXpress_003.bam testname3_9012
IonXpress_007.bam testname1_12345-
2-19-2016
IonXpress_001.bam testname5_00000
IonXpress_002.bam testname6_11111
IonXpress_003.bam testname7_1213
IonXpress_007.bam testname8_78524
```

**desired result**

```
testname1_12345.bam
testname2_45678.bam
testname3_9012.bam
testname1_12345.bam
file1.gz
file2.gz
```

**bash so far**

```
logfile=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-15-2016/process.log
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-15-2016/*.bam ; do
echo "patient identifier creation: $(date) - File: $f"
bname=$(basename $f)
pref=${bname%%.bam}
while read from to ; do
for i in $f* ; do
if [ "$i" != "${i/$from/$to}" ] ; then
  mv $i ${i/$from/$to}
fi
done < names.txt
echo "End patient identifier creation: $(date) - File: $f"
done >> "$logfile"
```

edit:

```
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2016/*.bam ; do
  bname=$(basename $f)
  cmd=$(sed -n "/$f/,/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-20[0-9]{2}/{s/\(.*\.bam\) \(.*\)/mv \1 \2/p}" /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/panels/names.txt)
  echo "$cmd"
done
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command
```

Comment: the date the of the folder ends in(`/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-15-2016`) will match a header in the `name` and that is where the match is located. Thank you very much :).

Comment: I apologize for that those were typos, there should be a always match somewhere in the file.  If there is no match then it should error. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `for` loop with `awk`:

```
cd /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/

for file in API/*/*.bam; do
   f="${file##*/}"
   path="${file%/*}"
   dt="${path##*/}"
   mv "$file" "$path/$(awk -v dt="$dt" -v f="$f" 'NF==1 {
               p=$0==dt ? 1 : 0; next} p && $1==f{print $2}' names.txt)"
done
```

Comment: the `for` loop with `awk` seems to work but I get `mv: ‘API/2-12-2016/IonXpress_001_newheader.bam’ and ‘API/2-12-2016/IonXpress_001_newheader.bam’ are the same file` for each one of the matching files, instead of renaming them.  Thank you very much :).

Comment: I have already tested this command and it worked fine on my system. Make sure your names.txt doesn't have DOS line endings. If it does have DOS line ending then run `dos2unix` on that file first.

Comment: To test `awk` independently use: `cd /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/; awk -v dt='2-15-2016' -v f=IonXpress_001_newheader.bam' 'NF==1 {p=$0==dt ? 1 : 0; next} p && $1==f{print $2}' names.txt` and see what output it gives.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this note I am using your f variable in the sed:

```
 cmd=$(sed -n "/$f/,/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-20[0-9]{2}/{s/\(.*\.bam\) \(.*\)/mv \1 \2/p}" names.txt)
 # for testing use echo and this will also save what you just tried 
 #to do to your log file :) just in case.
 echo "$cmd"
 # when it works the way you want
 # uncomment the next line and it will execute your command :)
 #eval "$cmd"
```

What this does is tells sed not to print lines it read with -n

then is says from the line that matches the date ($f) to the next data pattern which is DD-DD-20DD (regex: [0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-20[0-9]{2}) execute the command in between the {}

The command inside the {} is an substitute "s" command that will match a pattern and replace it with another one.

I tell it to take the string all the way to .bam and make that a group by putting it in between \( and \) then match the rest of the line and put that in another group

the replacement pattern is the mv string followed by the group 1 captured in the  match pattern and then followed by the string from group 2. effectively creating a list of mv file.bam new_filename commands.

this then stores them up in a cmd variable

eval will execute the command..

I took your example content of your name.txt file and did the transformation to illustrate:

```
 ~$echo "2-12-2016
 IonXpress_001.bam testname1_12345
 IonXpress_002.bam testname2_45678
 IonXpress_003.bam testname3_9012
 IonXpress_007.bam testname1_12345-
 2-19-2016
 IonXpress_001.bam testname5_00000
 IonXpress_002.bam testname6_11111
 IonXpress_003.bam testname7_1213
 IonXpress_007.bam testname8_78524" |sed -n "/$f/,/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-20[0-9]{2}/{s/\(.*\.bam\) \(.*\)/mv \1 \2/p}"
 mv IonXpress_001.bam testname1_12345
 mv IonXpress_002.bam testname2_45678
 mv IonXpress_003.bam testname3_9012
 mv IonXpress_007.bam testname1_12345-
 mv IonXpress_001.bam testname5_00000
 mv IonXpress_002.bam testname6_11111
 mv IonXpress_003.bam testname7_1213
 mv IonXpress_007.bam testname8_78524
```

**UPDATE:** From your comment and edit I see that I was not very good at explaining :) I here is an edited version of your script.
I will assume that you are in the the /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/ folder when you run this. if not I am sure you will know how to make the changes or make it take an argument.

```
 logfile=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-15-2016/process.log
 # no need to loop for each file ending in bam as the name file
 # will be our driver. After all if the entry is not present in
 # the name file then we really cannot do anything.

 # First lets get the date from the folder name:
 #    pwd will return the current working directory (which we are supposed 
 #        to be in the directory to process)
 #    basename will strip all but the last folder name, hence the date
 date_to_process=$(basename $(pwd))

 # variable to store name file path (hint change this to where it really is or pass as argument to script)
 name_file_path = "/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/panels/names.txt"

 # from the name file build the file move (mv) commmands using sed 
 # as described before and store that command in the cmd variable.
 # note that I added a couple of echo commands to have the same output you 
 # were trying to do. I also split the command on multiple lines 
 # for clarity (well I hope it makes it more clear at least).
 cmd=$(sed -n "/$date_to_process/,/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-20[0-9]{2}/{
    s/\(.*\.bam\) \(.*\)/echo \"Start patient identifier creation: \$(date) - File: \1\"\n mv \1 \2\n echo \"End patient identifier creation: \$(date) - File: \1\"/p
 }" $name_file_path)

 # print the generated commands to you can see what it did.
 echo "about to execute this command: 
 $cmd" 

 # execute the commands to perform the move operations and send the 
 #output to the log file. Make sure to pipe stderr (errors) to the log file 
 # too so you will know what/if something failed. (using 2>&1) this will make all stderr go to the same pipe as stdin. 
 eval "$cmd" >> "$logfile" 2>&1
```

Comment: I added an edit to the post, I am not doing something right.... Thank you very much :).

Comment: @Chris I updated my post with a simple script that should do what you need. I recommend commending out the eval line and making sure the script does what you want first (it will print the commands it generated so you can make sure it is what you want)

Comment: @Chris glad you got another answer.. I was thinking of using Awk and processing all your directory in one shot but I was not sure that was what you wanted. And there are about a thousand ways to tackle the same problem.. I tend to like creating a cmd variable or generating a temp script because I can setup a argument (usually -n) that will not actually do anything but will let me know what it would do.. That way I can make sure I got it right before running something that could sort of work and then have to figure out what worked what failed where etc..